# In HoTT, if $A$ and $B$ are both sets, then $A=B$ is a set

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In the HoTT book, it is mentioned that if $A,B$ are sets, then so does $A=B$ of paths between $A$ and $B$. Could someone tell me about how to prove this, please? Thank you.

With the help of the google hott-cafe :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hott-cafe/kTZKZQ13W4I

I think I got it:

As sketched in the comment in the linked post, $A=B$ is equivalent to $A\simeq B$ by univalence, and this is a subtype of $A \to B$, since $\sf isEquiv$ is a proposition. If $B$ is a set, then for any type $A$, the type $A \to B$ is also a set.

The last sentence is from example 3.1.6. For why we need that $\sf isEquiv$ is a proposition, it just means that the forgetful map : $A\simeq B \to (A \to B)$ is actually an embedding: If $f$ denotes an equivalence and $p$'s denotes the proof that $f$ is an equivalence, then as $A\simeq B$ is a proposition, we have $(f,p_1)= (f,p_2)$ so we do not need to worry if by forgetting $p_1$, $p_2$ of the same map $f$ we lose information.

Comment: They're types, not sets. Moreover I believe that $A, B: T \vdash A=B : Type$ is a formation rule, in other words this would be an axiom

Comment: @Max Sorry, they are indeed sets, but here my assumption is $A,B$ are sets defined in HoTT, not the sets in the usual sense. See https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1176-gde5c3b2.pdf page 107 for the definition of sets here.

Comment: @Max The HoTT book uses "set" to often mean an h-set, i.e. a type of homotopy level $0$ (for the $-2$ based indexing). That is, a type such that the values of the identity type between given terms of that type are unique. The problem then is to establish, given two types $A$ and $B$ satisfying that uniqueness of identity proofs condition, the identity type $A=B$ also satisfies that condition.

Comment: Ah ! I'm sorry I had misunderstood; my comment is then useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint to a possible solution.

If $A,B$ are sets then show that the type of equivalences $A\simeq B$ is a set. This shouldn't be too hard. Then by univalence...